# Swift: Optional tuple type in Assert statement

Tags: swift

I'm trying to implement a Priority Queue in Swift, and it's still in an initial stage. I would like to write tests for the data structure first.

Currently I have this method, `extractMin`, that returns the first element in the priority queue. It is implemented as follows (T is a generic value type).

```
//  Remove and return the element with minimum priority.
//  If the pq is empty, return nil.
func extractMin() -> (T, Double)? {
    return nil  //  Implementation goes here
}
```

I would like to write tests for this function. The first thing I will check is that it returns `nil` when the pq is empty. And I want to have something like this:

```
XCTAssertNil(priorityQueue.extractMin(), "A nil value should be returned when the priority queue is empty");
```

However, this is prompting me an errors that reads "(String, Double) is not identical to AnyObject".

Is there any way to fix this? How shall I go about writing tests for this kind of optional tuple types?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could consider returning a tuple of two optional values and check both? Or an optional class that has these two members.

This link also discusses the possibility of a missing "import Foundation" being the cause to this: http://www.scottlogic.com/blog/2014/09/24/swift-anyobject.html

Also see: [How can one use XCTAssertNil with optional structs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26684207/how-can-one-use-xctassertnil-with-optional-structs)